# Change CMake syntax colors in Clion

Tags: clion

I have installed CLion and custom configured a dark theme to make staring at the screen for long hours easier on the eyes. I was able to change every color for the C++ syntax configuration, but the color options for CMake are non-existent, and CMakes default colors are a very dark olive that requires me to strain my eyes to read. CMake shows up in code styles for changing tabbing, spacing, etc, but I cannot find color options anywhere in the settings menu.

Anyone in here that is a CLion user that can point me in the right direction?

Heres a screenshot of the CMake colors, prepare to squint
http://puu.sh/nxwtf/bd0625f791.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake change color in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607094/cmake-change-color-in-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, that functionality is missing.
> Please, vote for [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5352)!

The problem was resolved!

Additionaly you can get better coloring after
[CPP-33459](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-33459) Better coloring for `CMakeLists.txt`
You can get even more with the `cmake.highlight.all.completion.variables.only` registry key with `false`. CLion will distinguish all ids known for CMake. The colors need to be customized from default values.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make the file readable by changing the setting at Editor - Language Defaults - Identifiers - Default. I guess that isn't specific to CMakeLists.txt.