# Changing CLion's cmake colors

Tags: cmake, clion

Does anyone know how to change these colors?

[CMake tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLJTR.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Cmake syntax colors in Clion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835088/change-cmake-syntax-colors-in-clion)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to change the color of the tab in your image as it is set in the source code. See:

```
cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3::AppendEcho in cmLocalUnixMakefileGenerator3.cxx
```

Changing the color scheme in the source is straightforward, but you will also have to patch up, should you choose to follow this method. However, I would recommend trying the option below first.

---

**Alternatively**, you can try putting this piece of "code" at the top of your Cmake heade file (it sometimes works and it *doesn't* work sometimes):

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(red2yellow ALL 
    COMMAND find ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -name build.make 
            -exec perl -pi -e "s/--red/--yellow/" "{}" "\;")
```

This piece of code changes the color of the linking message to a shade of yellow, just as an example. If it doesn't work, you can resort to the first method.

This was obtained from

> [**CMake.org: changing the cmake color scheme**](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/changing-the-cmake-color-scheme-td5497400.html) - *Online forum*