# How can I change the colors used in CMake-generated Makefile messages?

Tags: cmake, makefile, customization, gnu-make, terminal-color

I have a somewhat lower capability of telling apart dark(er) blue from black on a monitor. Unfortunately, when CMake-generated Makefiles report the generation of an atypical target, they often/always print a message in Dark Blue color.

Can I get CMake to generate Makefiles which use a different color? Alternatively, is there some environment variable I can set to affect the colors the Makefile's will use?

Comment: Looks like [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607094/cmake-change-color-in-makefile) is exactly about your problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: So, that question has two answers. The accepted answer, which doesn't answer the question at all, and another one. I would mark this Q as a dupe if the other answer to the other question was accepted.

Comment: The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24661002/3440745) tells that colors are hardcoded at CMake side and it is impossible to change them. Not sure how accepting it would change your situation.